# TableView Not Showing on View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to display a UITableView and its cells in a UIViewController but I am not seeing the UITableView appear in the UIViewController. My AutoLayout constraints have the table set to appear underneath the "My Trips" UILabel. I've added the delegate and data source, not sure what I'm missing here.

[image]

```
class TripsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    //components
    let viewTitle = UILabel()
    let tripsTableView = UITableView()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        style()
        layout()
    }
}


extension TripsViewController {
    
    func setup(){
        tripsTableView.delegate = self
        tripsTableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func style() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        viewTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewTitle.text = "My Trips"
        viewTitle.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        
        tripsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    func layout() {
        view.addSubview(viewTitle)
        view.addSubview(tripsTableView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            viewTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            viewTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            tripsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            tripsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: viewTitle.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 2)
        ])
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "This is row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't given your table view a Trailing or Bottom constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are super close here.
The issue lies with your constraints.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    viewTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    viewTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    tripsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    tripsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: viewTitle.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    tripsTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: self.view.rightAnchor, multiplier: 1),
    tripsTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
])
```

you can see here I added in a right anchor and a height of 200.

Table View Appears.

Answer (score 1):

Add Trailing and Bottom constraints for your table view:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        viewTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        viewTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        tripsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        tripsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: viewTitle.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        
        // add these constraints
        view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: tripsTableView.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: tripsTableView.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the UIViewController to a UITableViewController since I am using static cells (for now) in my code. I also overrode the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` functions.

Changed

```
class TripsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

to

```
class TripsViewController: UITableViewController {
```

Comment: you do not need to do this. Your issue is with your constraints. see my answer. table view appears with the same code you have with two modified constraints

Comment: Ah, yes - I figured two constraints would have been enough. I guess not, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set trailing and bottom(or height) constraints as well. It will set a correct frame of tableview.

Snippet:

```
tripsTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            tripsTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 2)
```

**Note: Set multiple as per your need**